# Paging and TLB operating system

Tags: operating-system

A hierarchical memory system that uses cache memory has cache access time of 50 nanosecond, main memory access time of 300 nanoseconds, 75% of memory requests are for read, hit ratio of 0.8 for read access and the write - through scheme is used. what will be the average access time of the system both for read and write requests.
A 157.5 ns
B 110 ns
C 75 ns
D 82.5 ns

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a blatantly obvious multiple-choice homework question.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is A,157.5ns for read and write
Explanation:-For 1)average_read_access_time = 0.8*50+0.2*(50+300)=110 ns.

2) a. For read & write average take 75% of overall read_access= .75*110 plus 25% of write, that are only from main memory= .25*300
    =.75*110+.25*300=157.5 ns.